# Getting a typeerror in replace punctuation with space

Tags: python

```py
# Remove file extension and leading digits
file = filename.split('.')[0].lstrip(string.digits)
# Replace punctuation characters with underscores
# t = {ord(i) : '_' for i in string.punctuation}
file = file.translate(t)
```

For the above code iam getting an error as follows:

```
file = file.translate(t)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

But it is showing that t should be a character buffer object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.maketrans()` to create the mapping table.

```
table = file.maketrans(string.punctuation, '_' * len(string.punctuation))
file = file.translate(table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
t = {ord(i) : ord('_') for i in string.punctuation}
file = file.translate(t)
```